# jQuery this parent prev selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need hide the current image and show the video box that is a cousin of the parent element

I have this:

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#preview-box-playvideo-btn").click(function(){
  $(this).closest("#preview-box-img").css("display","none");
  $(this).closest("#preview-box-img").prev().fadeIn(600);
 });
});
</script>
```

```html
<div class="prev-img">
   <div id="preview-box-video">
    <embed id="" width="348" height="196" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" allowscriptaccess="always" quality="high" bgcolor="#000000" name="my-video" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/kRyPMsYGb74?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer&ps=play&vq=large&rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&authuser=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <div id="preview-box-closevideo-btn">X</div>
   </div>
   <div id="preview-box-img">
    <img src="http://www.img3.9minecraft.net/France/Texture-Pack/Atherys-ascended-texture-pack-3.jpg" height="196" width="348">
    <div id="preview-box-playvideo-btn">
     <span>Reproducir video</span>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Please, I need help I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have more than one element with `id="preview-box-img"` because if you do that is not allowed in  your page.  Use a class name instead.

Comment: Also, instead of `.css("display","none");`, use `.hide()`.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/1qer702n/  so you must either have duplicate IDs in your page or you have some sort of script error which you can see in the debug console.

Answer (score 1):

You're using ids in the html, but then you use selectors like you were using classes. I prefer using classes but in your case given your ids it's simpler.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
$("#preview-box-playvideo-btn").click(function(){
    $("#preview-box-img").hide();
    $("#preview-box-video").fadeIn(600);
});
```

});

It's nonsense to have ids and then traverse the dom tree when you can use the ids to select the elements directly (like you do when assigning the click event to the button).

If you do it by using classes it's safer to locate the containing div for both elements with closest and then locating the children from it with find.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you show here, the `prev()` selector actually does work. From what you describe, I assume that you say it is not working, because the video is not showing up. Is that right?

Don't know why you decided to use the `<embed>` tag to embed a youtube video. The prefered way would be to use an `iframe`. If you go to the video on youtube and click on "Share" -> "Embed", you get the following code that you can use on your site: `<iframe width="348" height="196" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kRyPMsYGb74" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Here a demo using `iframe` instead of `embed`. Also a css to hide the video at first. As you can see, your JS is the same and it works just fine hiding the image and showing the video.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".preview-box-playvideo-btn").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".preview-box-img").css("display", "none");
    $(this).closest(".preview-box-img").prev().fadeIn(600);
  });
});
```

```css
.preview-box-video {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prev-img">
  <div class="preview-box-video">
    <iframe width="348" height="196" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kRyPMsYGb74" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <div class="preview-box-closevideo-btn">X</div>
  </div>
  <div class="preview-box-img">
    <img src="http://www.img3.9minecraft.net/France/Texture-Pack/Atherys-ascended-texture-pack-3.jpg" height="196" width="348">
    <div class="preview-box-playvideo-btn"><span>Reproducir video</span>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have more than one "#preview-box-img" and I want to hide the current image that is clicked and show the "#preview-box-video" But I don't understand why it doesn't work to do that :s

Comment: As others have mentioned on their answers. Basically, if you have the same id name (#preview-box-img) for more than one element in your HTML, that is a good hint that you should be using classes instead. I've updated my answer to uses `class` instead of `id`. See if that works for you.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have the same `div` in your document you can use:

```
$("#preview-box-img").css("display","none");
$("#preview-box-img").prev().fadeIn(600);
```

If this code don't work, you should be sure that your click handler is ok.